# Firebase Query Snapshot returning null for a timestamp field instead of any value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

We have a 'react-native' application which uses Firestore Database to retrieve some information. We use the `react-native-firebase` package:

```
"react-native-firebase": "^4.1.0",
```

We have a query that used to work and after some updates has stopped working. For our date fields which are of the timestamp type, they return null in the snapshot query.

```
    firestore
      .collection("multiplayerrooms")
      .doc(result.id)
      .collection("playerAttempts")
      .orderBy("completeTimeInSeconds")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        playerAttemptsLength = querySnapshot.size;
        playerAttempts = querySnapshot.docs;
        console.log("player attempts");
        console.log(querySnapshot);
```

[image]
As shown above this is for the dateComplete field value.

If I look in Firebase console I can see there is a value for the doc in question.
[image]

If I hover over the field I can see the timestamp type showing up. I know the issue is not with parsing the value as we are getting null back before that timestamp is parsed to date format.

I found that it might relate to the firebase settings value: `timestampsInSnapshots` however setting this to true or false has no difference.

```
firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: false });
            firestore
              .collection("multiplayerrooms")
              .doc(result.id)
...
```

Any information as to why the timestamp field value is being returned null in the query snapshot data?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Apologies we use both for different bits, I should have been clear this is for Cloud Firestore Database